# Broadcast receiver registered from code

Tags: android, screen, broadcastreceiver

I register receiver from the onCreate from my activity like this

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenOnOffReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

And everything works good and the receiver get the intents, and everything is working good until, i close the activity. When I close the activity the method doesn't receive intents any more...

Does someone one know how can I register for receiver . . .

Note : I do not unregistered the receiver , but it happens somehow magically it just stop working properly . . .

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not doing it in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: This kind of broadcast receivers can not be registered in manifest. If would be possible to have the registering in manifest it would be great, but it is not possible !

Comment: @Lukap I know this is an old post, but did you find a way to register the ACTION_SCREEN_ON so you can receive broadcasts even when the activity is not active?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of registering a broadcast receiver in an activity is to get notified of some event while the activity is on (register the receiver in onResume, unregister it in onPause).

If you need a broadcast receiver to handle the event while the activity isn't showing, then register your broadcast receiver in your manifest.

If you need to handle both cases in a different way, then use a ordered broadcast.

Comment: It is not possible to register Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON in manifest :-( .that is my problem. I am searching for workaround, I want my broadcast receiver to receive messages all the time (all the time when my phone is on)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive messages all the time than you will need to create your own service and do your intent filter in onStartCommand method and unregister in onDestroy.

More details here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html